# Python not updating Mongo collection

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, endpoint

I built a flask app in python that receives a name value in a endpoint.
This name string is received correctly.
Then I access my collection on MongoDB to check if this name exists.
This perform ok.

My problem is when I'm trying to update the document on MongoDB. The code does not show any error message even if I run the command directly on Mongo. But it simply do not update de document when I run the python file.

I've tried all update functions I found on internet. Does anyone how where is the problem and how can I solve it?

```py
    @app.route('/check/<name>', methods=['GET'])
    def check_access(name):
        for x in db.collection.find({}, {'_id': 0, 'name': 1}):
            y = f'{x}'
            start = "{'name' : "
            end = ".0}"
            cliente_access = y[y.find(start) + len(start):y.rfind(end)]
            if name == cliente_access:
                query_access = {"name": name}
                update_access = {"$set":{"check_access": 1}}
                db.collection.update_one(query_access, update_access)
```

Comment: which version of mongo are you using?

Comment: currently 4.2.6

Comment: I couldn't understand the role of `cliente_acess`, but if you're sure that your condition is true, you could try using `query_access = {"name": x["name"]}`